# Segmentation fault while using delete in c++

Tags: c++, linux, pointers, char, constants

I am getting seg fault while trying to delete a pointer(for char array). Please help me. Am i doing anything wrong here. Please find the code snippet and output below.

Code :

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        int *p = new int;
        const char* c = new char[100];
        c = " hello";
        *p = 10;
        cout << "c= " << c << "*p = " << *p << endl;
        delete p;
        delete c;
        c = NULL;
        p = NULL;
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
c=  hello*p = 10
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Edit :

If i do not use new and delete for a character array, Is it a memory leak? I can not use string in my code, so what is the correct way to use const char* variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When programming in C++ you should read about and learn to use the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), it will help you a great deal. For example, instead of using pointers for strings, you should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You allocate memory and assign it to the pointer `c` here

```
const char* c = new char[100];
```

**But** then you reassign the pointer:

```
c = " hello";
```

That means you loose the original pointer, and now `c` points to the literal string `"hello"` which you can't delete.

What you should to instead is [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) the string into the allocated memory.

Comment: If i do not use new and delete for a character array, Is it a memory leak? I can not use string in my code, so what is the correct way to use const char* variable?

Comment: @user2599593 You can declare `c` as a normal character array (e.g. `char c[100];`) and it would be the same thing, but you don't have to free the memory (it's handled by the compiler). However, you must still copy the literal string into the array.

Answer (score 4):

You are making `c` point to a string literal here:

```
c = " hello";
```

then you attempt to delete it

```
delete c;
```

This is undefined behaviour. And you leak the array `c` pointer to originally.

Note: if `c` pointed to the original dynamically allocated array, you would need to delete it by calling `delete []`, not `delete`. Also, in C++ you would usually avoid such manual memory allocation:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string c = "hello";
  int p = 10;
  std::cout << "c= " << c << ", p = " << p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This should be delete [] c.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = " hello";
```

Makes it point to a static const char buffer(string literal) that you don't have control on. It does not copy the string in the array. When calling delete on this kind of memory, you get the crash.

You will also never be able to free the originally allocated memory.

If you want to do so:

```
delete [] c;
```

is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

your code is trying to delete a variable in read only data section, hence getting a segmentation fault.
And the code also contains a memory leak, `c = new char[100]` causes to allocated 100 bytes, and then the c pointer points to the "hello" literal, hence the address that was received using new is lost, hence a memory leak..
use string copy function to copy the literal "hello" to the allocated memory.